# Very rarely Rails 5 update_attributes is not running UPDATE in SQL for Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Using Postgres 9.5.2

It's only happened twice in the past 2 days, and I've been doing the same things as normal testing out webhooks for stripe, so I've been resetting the user a bunch of times to run them through my wizard clean. But that means that I've been doing the same actions over and over and I can't really think what's distinguishing these times over the others.

```
> u.update_attributes role: :customer, stripe_account_id: nil
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (6.7ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."name") = LOWER($1) AND ("users"."id" != $2) LIMIT $3  [["name", "Conan"], ["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."username") = LOWER($1) AND ("users"."id" != $2) LIMIT $3  [["username", "mcb"], ["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  FriendlyId::Slug Load (17.7ms)  SELECT  "friendly_id_slugs".* FROM "friendly_id_slugs" WHERE "friendly_id_slugs"."sluggable_id" = $1 AND "friendly_id_slugs"."sluggable_type" = $2 ORDER BY "friendly_id_slugs".id DESC LIMIT $3  [["sluggable_id", 1], ["sluggable_type", "User"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
----> # NO UPDATE RUN!!!!!!
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT
=> true
[74] pry(main)> u.reload
  User Load (17.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<User id: 1, email: "mcb@email.com", name: "Conan", username: "mcb",
     created_at: "2016-12-02 02:37:43", updated_at: "2016-12-15 20:30:39",
     slug: "mcb", role: "pending_id",
     ..., stripe_customer_id: nil, acts_as_deleted: false,
     stripe_account_id: "acct_0000", first_name: "Joey", last_name: "JoeJoe", ...>

> u.update_attributes role: :customer, stripe_account_id: nil
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."name") = LOWER($1) AND ("users"."id" != $2) LIMIT $3  [["name", "Conan"], ["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."username") = LOWER($1) AND ("users"."id" != $2) LIMIT $3  [["username", "mcb"], ["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
---> (now runs??) SQL (6.2ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "updated_at" = $1, "role" = $2, "stripe_account_id" = $3 WHERE "users"."id" = $4  [["updated_at", 2016-12-15 20:37:07 UTC], ["role", 0], ["stripe_account_id", nil], ["id", 1]]
=> u.reload #=> reloads with `role` as `customer` and `stripe_account_id` `nil`
```

Comment: The difference I see is this line starting: `FriendlyId::Slug Load` - the later one (that works) doesn't have this line... I suspect that something failed at the stripe end - the user couldn't be found (maybe the request timed out) and it's falling back to searching by slug... but the second run through it finds the user successfully and then goes ahead and updates it. You might want to talk with stripe about whether there's a glitch?

Comment: Both times it happened in the console. Yesterday I just dismissed it as I figured I was tired and probably just imagining the problem. But I don't think I was making an api call to Stripe directly before using `update_attributes`. either time.

Comment: hmm, so the `FriendlyId::Slug Load` is something local to your db... well you may need to look into your code to see where that is happening - if it only happens when it fails, then you've got a clue (even if not a very good one) as to what might be going wrong.

Comment: Sorry, `FriendlyId::Slug` is usually called after `UPDATE`. I just copied down to the UPDATE line to highlight the difference, but in hindsight that was a mistake.